# Modal Pop Up not showing when clicking HREF

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am calling a modal Pop Up with a HREF and when I click it is supose to call a Modal but it is only making my background grey and it doesn't show nothing.
I have the following code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="test" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                HELLO MY PEOPLE
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The HREF click:

```
<a href="#test" data-toggle="modal" class="more-link"></a>
```

Am I doing something wrong? It's my bootstrap CSS messed up? When I change the modals to Containers it shows, but it Shows in a bad way and I really need the modals, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: working fine without any changes:- https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/to027vhg/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can open modal by using data-target:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test" class="more-link"></a>
```

Comment: why you using `javascript.void(0)` here? by putting it you can disable javascript! so be aware before putting any answer.< in short dhyan rakho >

Answer (score 0):

The code which used itself should work fine without any issues. Add the data-target attribute to your anchor tag and see if it works.

Change your anchor tag code as I mentioned below. This should work fine.

```
<a href="#test" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test" class="more-link"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my local machine and it works fine, but some CSS properties can create a problem like that.

please check some steps

- your `z-index` is greater than your body or parent tag
- you have `data-target` property in your anchor tag
- must include `jquery & bootstrap.js` script in your file

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="modal fade" id="test" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Stackoverflow</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                HELLO MY PEOPLE
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#test" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test" class="more-link">Open Modal</a>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!